# Some powershell commands won't run when called from python

Tags: python, powershell, subprocess, office365

I'm having some difficulties successfully running a powershell script that's part of my python script. The issue isn't that the script doesn't run, commands from installed powershell modules aren't recognized even if I attempt to import. The commands specifically are the Connect-MSOLService and other commands in the same module.

I wrote a small test to try our different things but nothing seems to work. In the test i've tried the following:

`subprocess.call('powershell ./script.ps1"')`

or

`p = subprocess.Popen(['powershell.exe', '-NoProfile', '-Command', '"&{' + pscommand + '}"'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
p.communicate()`

or

`subprocess.call('powershell.exe ./script.ps1"')`

All of these run the script successfully except for the MSOL commands, always returns the this error:

`Connect-MsolService : The term 'Connect-MsolService' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file,
or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and
try again.
At C:\Users\user\desktop\scripts\script.ps1:20 char:9
+         Connect-MsolService -Credential $LiveCred
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Connect-MsolService:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException`

When running from outside of python script works fine, execution policy is set to unrestricted, problem only occurs when I use subprocess.call() in Python. Any ideas/help will be much appreciated.

Thanks,
Lou

Comment: In the script, if you import the PowerShell module containing `Connect-MsolService` does it run then?

Comment: Unfortunately no, adding import-module MSOnline does not make a difference

Comment: It should make some difference. Doesn't a new error appear when powershell fails to load the `MSOnline` module? Try outputting `Get-ChildItem -path 'env:\PSModulePath'` to see if the MSOnline module's location is in the module path for your child powershell process.

Comment: What version of Powershell, Python and Windows are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
subprocess.call('C:\\Windows\\sysnative\\windowspowershell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe -executionpolicy bypass ./script.ps1')
```

After trying this and getting the same error. I found Python was calling the 32-Bit version of PowerShell and failing to import the 64 bit module. The above code is able to call the 64 bit version of PowerShell from the 32-Bit Python that then runs the script that contains 
[Connect-MsolService].